# Can't Capture CPU Metrics in VS 2010 Performance Analyzer

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I'm using the Performance Analyzer in Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying to profile CPU Counters such as `Last Level Cache Misses`, but no matter what I've tried I cannot see the captured counter data in the resulting reports.

Here is my configuration:

- Running VS as Administrator
- The project is set to Debug x64 (*also tried Release x64*)

**General**

- Profiling Collection: *Instrumentation* (*also tried 'Sampling'*)
- Data collection control: *enabled*

**Sampling**

- Sample event: *Performance counter*
- Sampling interval: *1000*
- Selected Counter: *Portable Events --> Memory Events --> Last Level Cache Misses*

**CPU Counters**

- Collect CPU Counters: *enabled*
- Selected counters: *Portable Events --> Memory Events --> Last Level Cache Misses*

I found an article that describes the process (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/06/22/cpu-performance-counters-in-visual-studio-2010-profiler.aspx), but I can't get the results to show up anywhere. Clearly I am doing something wrong, can any suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the system I was using was a Hyper-V instance. Consequently, processor metrics like L2 Cache are not available because it's a virtual environment.